# Is there a way to specify where store.js is added to the page?

Tags: expresso-store, javascript, jquery

Working on a product page using Expresso Store and I'm encountering an intermittent javascript  error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - store.js:142
```

It looks like a dependency problem (store.js depends on jQuery). The store.js is being added to the page asynchronously in the footer of the `{exp:store:product}` tag whereas jQuery is added to the page at the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>`. Depending on network performance and what is cached in the browser, occasionally the store.js loads before jQuery has loaded.

I dont want to move jQuery to the page header, so is there a way to specify where Expresso injects its JS (eg: a special JS template tag) or is there a way to force the store.js script tag to be synchronous and hence enforce the script loading order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: Store 2 includes the fix mentioned below.

---

It will be an option in the next version. In the meantime, you can fix it by opening `mod.store.php`, going down to about line 235, and changing this:

```
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(script);
```

to this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
```

That should make sure the `store.js` script is added to the bottom of the page, after jQuery and other scripts.

Comment: Adrian, how would this answer differ for Store 2.x?

Comment: In Store 2 the change above is implemented by default, so you should have no problem loading jQuery and other scripts in your page footer.